# Passing Data in Login and Register Page Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, authentication, view

I create login and register function in Laravel 6 with scaffold function, and i got this LoginController:

```
<?php
...
...
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

I want to pass a data `DB::table('terms_condition')->get()` to login view, how should i do?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @petersowah cause i want to display the terms and condition from database to view page

Comment: Why not have it as a static page instead? Any reason you want to store in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Put this method in  `LoginController`

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
   $terms_condition = DB::table('terms_condition')->get();
   return view('auth.login',compact('terms_condition'));
}
```

`showLoginForm()` is from `AuthenticatesUsers` trait which is used by your `LoginController`. You have to put this method in `LoginController`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your login controller rewrite the function showLoginform

```
  public function showLoginForm()
    {
`      $data = DB::table('terms_condition')->get();
        return view('frontend.auth.login',compact('data'));
    }
```

Or From your LoginController you can see that AuthenticateUsers 
go to the Authenticate Users file and edit the showLoginForm as like this

```
public function showLoginForm()
    {
`      $data = DB::table('terms_condition')->get();
        return view('frontend.auth.login',compact('data'));
    }
```

And dont forget to use DB in the top

Answer (score 0):

You can override the built-in `showLoginForm()` method in the LoginController

LoginController.php

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login',['terms'=>DB::table('terms_condition')->get()]); //pass your data here as a second argument
    }
}
```

You can then access this in your blade view as `$terms`

Answer (score 0):

A different way to go about it: use a View Composer. This will run when the view is rendered so you can pass data to it this way:

```
view()->composer('auth.login', function ($view) {
    $view->with('something', DB::table(...)->get());
});

// or View::composer(...) if you prefer
```

You can add that at a Service Provider's `boot` method. No overriding anything.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Views - View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers) `View::composer()`